# Java - NoSuchMethodException

Tags: java, web-services, exception

I have created a custom exception class to handle all my project's errors.
It's linked to a SOAP web service, that's why there is `@WebFault`.

```
@WebFault(name = "GTWFaultBean", targetNamespace = "http://www.test.com")
public class GTWException extends Exception implements Serializable
{   
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 6512673270706929264L;
private String errorDescription;
private String errorLocation;

public GTWException(String errorDescription, String errorLocation) {
    super();
    this.errorDescription = errorDescription;
    this.errorLocation = errorLocation;
}

public String getException()
{
    String error = "location:"+errorLocation+"|*SEP*|"+"description:"+errorDescription;
    return error;
}

public int getExceptionId()
{
    int exceptionId = 1;
    if(errorDescription!=null)
    {
        exceptionId = 0;
    }
    return exceptionId;
}

public static String toString(Throwable th) {
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
    th.printStackTrace(pw);
    return sw.toString();
  }

}
```

Here is my console output

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: lu.br.ged.exception.GTWException.<init>(java.lang.String)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createUserDefinedException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:312)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:130)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:108)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:78)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:135)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.create(Unknown Source)
at controller.WSconsumer.consumeWS(WSconsumer.java:69)
at controller.WSconsumer.main(WSconsumer.java:87)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: lu.br.ged.exception.GTWException.<init>(java.lang.String)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2892)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1723)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createUserDefinedException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:308)
... 7 more
```

I searched a lot by myself but I couldn't figure the problem out.

EDIT :

As proposed, I added a new constructor with a single string argument.

The error has changed to

```
exception.GTWException
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createUserDefinedException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:309)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:130)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:108)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:78)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:135)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.create(Unknown Source)
at controller.WSconsumer.consumeWS(WSconsumer.java:69)
at controller.WSconsumer.main(WSconsumer.java:87)
```

What am I Doing wrong ?

Comment: You Need a constructor with only one Parameter of type string

Comment: It seems to be looking for a constructor with a single string argument, and you don't have one.

Comment: @Jens I added a constructor with one parameter of type string. Now I get a new error `NativeConstructorAccessorImpl`. Do you suggest me to do a new post about this error ?

Comment: Add the complete Stacktrace as update to your question

Comment: @Jens Ok, I added the new stacktrace.

Comment: did you create also an empty constructor?

Comment: No i didn't, should I ?